# How to use multiple count and where condition sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this two query

1.

```
select CL_Clients.cl_id,CL_Clients].cl_name,COUNT(*) AS number_of_orders
from CL_Clients,CLOI_ClientOrderItems
where CL_Clients.cl_id=CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
group by CL_Clients.cl_name,CL_Clients.cl_id
```

2.

```
select CL_Clients.cl_id,count(cloi_current_status) as dis
from CLOI_ClientOrderItems,CL_Clients
where cloi_current_status]='12'
and CL_Clients.cl_id=CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
group by CL_Clients.cl_name,CL_Clients.cl_id,CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cloi_current_status
```

i have this column i need to put count function and where condition

[cloi_current_status]
166
30
30
30
150
150
150
150
150
150
150

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to join that two query in single

Comment: You need to be more specific. Try to show an example of the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

All depends on what data you are trying to get, but you can go about it like this.

```
SELECT Column_x, Column_y, etc..
FROM ClL_Clients a
JOIN (select CL_Clients.cl_id,CL_Clients].cl_name,COUNT(*) AS number_of_orders
from CL_Clients,CLOI_ClientOrderItems
where CL_Clients.cl_id=CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
group by CL_Clients.cl_name,CL_Clients.cl_id) b

on a.cl_id = b.cl_id

JOIN (select CL_Clients.cl_id,count(cloi_current_status) as dis
from CLOI_ClientOrderItems,CL_Clients
where cloi_current_status]='12'
and CL_Clients.cl_id=CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
group by CL_Clients.cl_name,CL_Clients.cl_id,CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cloi_current_status) c

on a.cl_id = c.cl_id
Group by BLAH BLAH
```

Hope this gets you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple, you just encapsulate the queries and give their result sets an alias and then do a JOIN between their aliases on the column that is common. (In the query below I ***assume*** you'll be joining by client id)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT CL_Clients.cl_id,
        CL_Clients].cl_name,
        COUNT(*) AS number_of_orders
    FROM CL_Clients,
        CLOI_ClientOrderItems
    WHERE CL_Clients.cl_id = CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
    GROUP BY CL_Clients.cl_name,
        CL_Clients.cl_id
    ) A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CL_Clients.cl_id,
        count(cloi_current_status) AS dis
    FROM CLOI_ClientOrderItems,
        CL_Clients
    WHERE cloi_current_status] = '12'
        AND CL_Clients.cl_id = CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
    GROUP BY CL_Clients.cl_name,
        CL_Clients.cl_id,
        CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cloi_current_status
    ) B
    ON A.cl_id = B.cl_id
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
```

This will be treated as a separate result set, so you can also filter results with a `WHERE` or just a `GROUP BY`, just like in a normal `SELECT`.

**UPDATE:**

To answer the question in your comments, when you join two tables that have a column with the same value and use

`SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B` the `*` will show all columns returned by the join, meaning all columns from A and all columns from B, this is why you have duplicate columns.

If you want to filter the columns returned you can specifiy which columns you want returned. So, in your case, the top `SELECT *` can be replaced with

`SELECT A.cl_id, A.cl_name, A.number_of_orders, B.dis` so, your query becomes:

```
SELECT A.cl_id, A.cl_name, A.number_of_orders, B.dis
FROM (
    SELECT CL_Clients.cl_id,
        CL_Clients].cl_name,
        COUNT(*) AS number_of_orders
    FROM CL_Clients,
        CLOI_ClientOrderItems
    WHERE CL_Clients.cl_id = CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
    GROUP BY CL_Clients.cl_name,
        CL_Clients.cl_id
    ) A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CL_Clients.cl_id,
        count(cloi_current_status) AS dis
    FROM CLOI_ClientOrderItems,
        CL_Clients
    WHERE cloi_current_status] = '12'
        AND CL_Clients.cl_id = CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
    GROUP BY CL_Clients.cl_name,
        CL_Clients.cl_id,
        CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cloi_current_status
    ) B
    ON A.cl_id = B.cl_id
```

**UPDATE #2**:

For your last question, you need to `GROUP BY` at the end of the big query and use a `HAVING` condtion, like this:

```
GROUP BY A.cl_id, A.cl_name, A.number_of_orders, B.dis
HAVING COUNT(cloi_current_status) > 100
```

Comment: @user3445262 Two columns or rows?

Comment: ok thanks and one more i have cloi_current_status column in my talble i want put count function with where condition

Comment: @user3445262 I don't know what logic you're trying to apply. Edit your question and add more details.

Comment: @user3445262 I replied.

Comment: see ihave adde colunm in that numbers r there each no indicates diff msg i mean 30 means dispath and 150 means file held like that msg are there so now i am counting number of customer under that msg

Comment: @user3445262 I don't understand what you're asking. Plus, I have answered more than the question you posted. You should ask another question and give more details.

Comment: instade of joining 2nd query is it possible to add it in single query no joins?

Comment: @user3445262 Not with the way you're grouping data.

Comment: everything is same as 1st query but in 2nd query i am checking with condition